# Line appearing beside image link

Tags: image, outlook, hyperlink, mailchimp

I haven't been able to figure out why this is happening. I'm using MailChimp to send out a newsletter and in Outlook 2003 am getting a line (similar to a hyphen) to the right of any image, that is a link. (see attached image)

http://clickstream.ie/img/line.png

Here is the code for the logo at the top:

```
<a href="#">
    <img alt="clickstream logo" title="clickstream logo" src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/0f36ab4eb559a3dd979199c25/images/clickstream_logo.jpg" style="max-width: 250px;border: 0;height: auto;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;vertical-align: bottom;" class="mcnImage" width="176">
</a>
```

Does anyone know why this would be happening, or has had any experience with this issue.

In Gmail and Hotmail (Outlook) it seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

That line might not be from the image, but from an `<hr>` code you might have included in the page somewhere. Now all you do is, try to change the position of each div around that area, to position: absolute; you might see other divs moving and leaving out that line. but if it does not then you have to check in your code and make sure you have the following correctly.

```
line-height: ;
outline:;
ertical-align:;
```

You might also undo any borders you have added to the div. but if not works, then it might be from your external stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rdnard.

I think I have it sorted now, I've added 'text-decoration: none' to any a elements (as it only occurred when an image was a link) and it seems to have gotten rid of the line, but the area where the line was is still a link, an invisible link if you will.

I think it's good enough for me though. Thanks for your help.